# SCM for a Large Modular Code Base

Tags: git, svn, version-control, mercurial, git-submodules

I need some help designing a SCM for my codebase. The codebase is fairly complex, so first, I will try to describe it.

The code base is made up of code for many different products, let's say `Product1` and `Product2` for simplicity (there are more in reality). Each `Product` has multiple software `Projects` associated with it, for example, the `Core Application`, and supporting software, such as `iOS` and `Android` apps (this varies from product to product). Each `Project` will need to use code common to it's `Product` (ie the `Core`, `iOS` and `Android` applciations all need to share some common code). Furthermore, `Products` need to share in-house libaries with one another.

Effectively, you end up with a structure like this:

```
Library1
Library2
Product1
├── Common
├── Core Application
├── iOS
└── Android
Product2
├── Common
├── Core Application
├── iOS
└── Android
```

The following features are absolutely required:

1. Ability to check out the minimal code set for a project - For example, if I want to build `Product1's` `Android` application, I only want to check out `Library1`, `Library2`, `Product1/Common`, `Product1/Android`. The code base is so vast checking out everything will take huge amounts of time
2. Revert the state of shared libraries, common code and project code to a specific revision - For example, I need to build `Product2's` `Core Application` as it was 2 months ago to test a bug, I need `Library1`, `Library2`, `Product2/Common` and `Product2/Core Application` to all revert to the same revision
3. Move files to different shared folders whilst maintaining history - It is impossible to put all of the correct code of a `Product` into the `Common` folder at the start. Changing requirements over time and new products are requested, meaning code that once lived in `Product2/Core Application` needs to move to `Product2/Common`, or maybe even `Library2`.

Currently, the system we are using is a huge SVN repository, that encompasses all `Products`, `Projects` and `Libraries`. Selective code checkouts are possible in SVN, so we can choose to checkout only specific folders. Because it is all one Repository, everything reverts to the same revision nicely. When we branch or tag, we branch/tag the entire repository!

What I would like to is properly modularize the code base so, for example, `Library1` lives in its own repository, and is simply included by other repositories. This is not really possible with `svn::externals`, as it breaks requirement 2.

I would like to use some form of DVCS, to for the following reasons:

1. Performance - SVN is slow when committing big changesets
2. Braching/Merging - Trying to merge big SVN branches is a nightmare, we avoid it at all costs. I know it is so much easier with a DVCS
3. Proper support for modules. I know Git has submodules and Mercurial has subrepos, which seem to fit with my design goal, but it seems with both you have to manually update subrepos when changing revision. I want it to be done in 1 simple step.
4. Clearer repository structure. Using subrepos, each project will be its own reposisotry, with a clear structure and clear set of dependencies

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

There have been some changes to Mercurial recently aimed at making subrepos easier and more efficient to use. I haven't been paying close attention to them - you might want to look at the recent [hg-crew](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/CrewRepository) commit history to see if there's anything in there that might influence your decision.

I've used both Git and Mercurial extensively, but definitely have a much deeper knowledge of Mercurial and much prefer to use it. I've migrated projects from ClearCase, SVN and Git to Mercurial and in all cases the transition has been pretty smooth - the important things are to have a couple of people who can set the workflows for your team and to set up representative test repos and try it first.

The [`hg convert` extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ConvertExtension) can convert repositories from various sources to a Mercurial repository, and can use a filemap to convert only part of the repo, rename files/directories, etc. I'm sure there's something similar on Git but I've never needed to use it.